# "Vulcanized" Polymer Paper-elements don't work in Cordova

Tags: cordova, polymer, paper-elements

I'm developing an HTML app with Cordova. I'm using the Crosswalk web views. I've been tried to use Polymer (v0.5) to integrate the [paper-elements](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/material.html) components. In the same way, I read  that isn't possible loading the html components using `<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-elements/paper-elements.html">`; the solution is use the [Vulcanize](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/concatenating-web-components.html) build tool, for concatenating the components in a single page.

I did all of that, but the app still not recognizing the paper-elements. I wrote a small example of my scenario, and is as follow:

The structure of the `www/` directory in my cordova project is:

```
    www/
      bower_components/
      css/
      html/
        index.html
        vulcanized.html
      img/
      js/
      bower.json
      index.html
```

The `www/index.html` are the generated of vulcanize building of the `www/html/index.html` archive. The last one is like this:

```
    <!doctype html>
     <html>
      <head>
       <title>Test Project</title>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
       <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
       <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">

       <link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-elements/paper-elements.html">


      </head>
      <body unresolved>

       <div id="login">
        <form>
         <paper-input label="Name" floatingLabel></paper-input>
         <br>
         <paper-input label="Password" floatingLabel></paper-input>
         <br>
         <paper-button toggle>Sign in</paper-button>
        </form>
       </div>

      </body>
     </html>
```

That works well in a local server, but it doesn't work at all in the Web View.

Does anybody help me with that? Isn't possible to use paper-elements with Cordova at all?

Thanks in advance!

 
Pedro.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js in HEAD?